# Deleting a particular SMS message works sometimes

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to delete particular SMS from given position on my list view. This works fine but not always. It works sometimes.. Sometimes doesn't delete at all.

I am not sure why this is happening can somebody let me know how to fix this up:

Here is what I am trying:

```
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/?simple=true"), null, null, null, null);

        if ( cursor.getCount() > 0 )
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        try 
        {

            String pid = cursor.getString(0); // Get id;
            String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                    null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
        cursor.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get exceptions? (You should print the complete stack trace `Log.e("try again", "", e);` so you can see what goes wrong btw)

Comment: No I dnt get any exceptions

Comment: `.delete` returns the number of deleted rows. Is that returning 1 all the time? (Would indicate a display related bug since something is actually deleted). You also can't be sure that the position in your listView is the same as the position in a freshly queried cursor. Use the id directly from the cursor you use for your listview instead.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. Yes. It returns 1 always. not sure what is getting deleted. Also what do you mean by Use the id directly from the cursor you use for your listview instead?

Comment: Also the item clicked is showing the same ID number..